# Jprofiler setup issue in windows jboss

Tags: jprofiler

Jprofiler is not getting setup in my local windows 64 environment. I did below setting in standalone.conf.bat in jboss 
 set "JAVA_OPTS=-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler9\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=11002"

JVM is not appearing in JProfiler.

Thanks
Pranav

Answer (score 0):

> JVM is not appearing in JProfiler

It would not appear automatically, you have to connect with a remote session that connects on port 11002. This only works if port 11002 is not used by anything else.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. I am connecting to local jvm only.  Jboss is installed  locally and Jprofiler also in my windows machine. Still issue is there

Comment: It does not matter if the application server is running locally on on another computer, if you add the -agentpath VM parameter to the Java invocation, the session type is always "Attach to remote JVM".